# Why, when specifying defaultValue in input, does the form handler not see this value?

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

There is a form made on react-hook-form, there is an input that receives a line in defaultValue, but when submitting the form, an error occurs that the field is not filled.

That is, you either need to press the submit button twice and then the form starts seeing the value in the input, or erase something, or add something.

How can you make defaultValue initially visible to the form handler?

using the react-hook-form api, namely setValue

Comment: *How can you make defaultValue initially visible to the form handler?* - you can't. Setup the form correctly https://www.react-hook-form.com/api/useform/#defaultValues